# Javascript inside a java code

Tags: java, javascript, jax-rs

I need to write a jax-rs endpoint which returns a javascript function.

I know that we can write java codes inside javascript. But I don't know weather we can write a javascript code inside a java code.

But my supervisor asked me to write it. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I didn't know that we can write Java codes inside JavaScript ....

Comment: If you want to return some text from JAX-RS that happens to be Javascript source code, then: yes, sure, no problem. If you want something else, please explain in more detail.

Comment: If you're returning a JavaScript function, from the perspective of the Java program, you're just constructing a string with a special format and returning it.

Comment: Search "jsonp". I'm guessing that's what your sup is referring to. Most JAX-RS implementaions have support for this. Otherwise either tell your sup to elaborate or give us some more information about the requirement you have been given but aren't telling us

Comment: We can run javascript from java, we can not run java from javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can return a string from your code and you can declare html tags as the returning String. I will suggest a sample code.

```
        @GET
        @Path("/")
        @Produces("text/html")
    public String getStatus(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    return "<html><head><script>put your java script code here...</script></head></html>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use run javascript code inside of java you should take a look at nashorn:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_%28JavaScript_engine%29

A very good tutorial on this here:
http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/04/05/java8-nashorn-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to execute JavaScript in the server.  You only need to return a String representation of the JavaScript function,  so the client can execute the returned code dynamically (for instance using `eval` inside the browser).

On the other hand,  if you want to run JavaScript inside the server you can use one of the embedded engines that are available inside the JVM:

Java 1.7: Rhino

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/

Java 8: Nashorn

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at  [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino)  or [Nashorn](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_(JavaScript_engine)).  The latter was released by Oracle with Java 8.

> Rhino is an open-source implementation of JavaScript written entirely in Java. It is typically embedded into Java applications to provide scripting to end users. It is embedded in J2SE 6 as the default Java scripting engine.
>
> Nashorn is a JavaScript engine developed in the Java programming language by Oracle. It is based on the Da Vinci Machine (JSR 292) and has been released with Java 8.